# Add custom field to CERTAIN cms pages

Tags: magento

I have found quite a number of tutorials for adding a field to the Magento CMS for any pages, but can this be done for just certain pages? E.g. for the homepage I would like to ask a number of different datapoints. I do not like the full WYSIWYG editor,

Comment: How would these datapoints be used?

Comment: A homepage has different content then an about page. I would like to have a field for each piece of content (e.g. title, text, promo link) and the customer fills these out instead of getting free reign to edit the entire page as WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Magento homepage has a unique "[layout handle](http://www.groovecommerce.com/ecommerce-blog/magento/developers-toolbox-get-a-handle-on-handles-in-magento-layout-xml/)"  called: `cms_index_index`.

You can add "blocks" and templates based on the layout in: `cms.xml`

Let us know if you need further assistance

**Update**

For adding custom fields in the backend for a specific CMS page try this:

1. Create and observer which detects which CMS page is being loaded in backend (the event you want to observe is: `adminhtml_cms_page_edit_tab_content_prepare_form`)
2. If it is correct display custom field

You can see this article for more info:
http://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-custom-attribute-to-a-cms-page/

Comment: This looks like it's for adding blocks to page output on website, hoping to be able to add fields to CMS. Example, for home page only - not every page - make it look like this: http://i49.tinypic.com/3c56e.jpg

Comment: Try this article: http://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-custom-attribute-to-a-cms-page/

Comment: Any idea for doing this in Magento 2?